# I would like to know how to select all files with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, file, selenium-webdriver, explorer

I am trying to select all files with python selenium.

```
dir = os.chdir("C:\\Users\\adam\\OneDrive - Wheelers Lane Technology College\\Pictures\\ama")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    print(file)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="upl-fileInp"]').send_keys(file)
```

This is what I have and it lists all the files in a directory, but I don't know how to select it.

Comment: What do you mean by you want to select all files ? select is not upload ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to upload a file with Selenium you have to send it absolute path including the file name to the `input` element.
Something like this

```py
for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\adam\\OneDrive - Wheelers Lane Technology College\\Pictures\\ama\\*.jpg"):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]').send_keys(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

To select elements by clicking on them, you use Javascript's click()

```
files = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="upl-fileInp"]').send_keys(file)
for element in files:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```